# BlueSnap Subscription Fail simulation

Tags: api, subscription, bluesnap

Is there any way to simulate bluesnap. what happens when a recurring payment fails, for example, if the user doesn't have money on the card in that moment?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlueSnap offers **IPN** (Instant Payment Notification) alerts for events such as declined CC charge for a subscription. This type of IPN is defined as "on demand" - which means you will need to register to receive it in the BlueSnap control panel.

https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/on-demand-ipns

Since the IPNs are messages sent over HTTP, you can choose to send them to your server, and configure a receiver for it there. Once the IPN reached your server it can be parsed by your receiver and you can choose what to do with it, for example:

- send an automated email to your customer support or accounting department
- send an email to the shopper
- log the event in your system for later analysis.

IPNs can also be sent manually, thus simulating this event. For you specific case, the IPN for *CC_CHARGE_FAILED* can by opening a browser with a connection that can access your server, and putting the IPN in the address line. Your receiver will get the information and respond accordingly.

If you already received an IPN for an actual CC charge failure - use that IPN message as is. If you have not yet received such an IPN and in fact you're just starting out and building your own receiver, you should contact BlueSnap merchant support at merchants@bluesnap.com and they'll send you a sample.